# Getting list of applications that uses certain permission

Tags: java, android, collections, permissions

I am currently able to retrieve the list of permission for all application, but is there a way to get a list of the applications that use a certain permission?

With this code I am able to get the list of permissions of a certain package in my application.

```
    PackageInfo pkgInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                packageName, 
                PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
              );
```

But what I want is to get a list of applications that use, for example, the INTERNET permission.

Can I do it with a collection class, as suggested below. If so with what collection?

Comment: Sorry, what's your question exactly?

Comment: I am assuming there is not a method to just do it. So you will have to iterate through all the apps adding the permissions to a collection (chose a collection that helps with the next bit), and then query the collection for all apps that have permission X.

Comment: A bidirectional multimap would be ideal, but I don't know of one. Or a simple multimap than transpose it to another multimap

Comment: A `Map<CharSequence,Collection<String>>`, for example, would be suitable. You can then populate the map with the names of the permissions, each mapped to a number of 0..n application names (as `String`s) in this example; implementations to use could be `HashMap` for the map and `ArrayList` for the collection from the collections API.

Comment: Would there any sample code that demonstrate the above suggestion? I am still pretty new at android atm